# I want to read in strings to the new line character in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a long text file that I am trying to pull certain strings out of. The length of these strings are variable with the text file but are always located after certain identifiers. So for example say my text file looks like this:

junk text...

Name:
Age:

Robert

twenty
four.

junk text...

I always know that the "Robert" string is located at "Age:\n\n" but I am not sure how long it is only that it will end at a "\n\n" and the same principle with the "twenty four." string. I have tried using

namepos1 = string.find("Age:")

namepos2 = namepos1 + 6

this will give the starting location of the string I want but I do not know how to save it into a variable such that it always saves the whole string up to the two new line characters. If it was a set length and not variable I think I could use:

name = string[namepos2:length]

but any help would be greatly appreciated. I may have to go about doing it completely different, but this is the first way I have thought about it and tried to do it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by finding age, then moving forward your cursor two lines if you would like to do that, if you want the entire section of text after the "junk", and you know how long that text is, this would also work:

```
lookup = 'age'
lines=[]
with open('C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/Summer 2016/Programs/untitled5.txt') as myFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
        if lookup in line:
            lines.append(num+2)
ofile=open('C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/Summer 2016/Programs/untitled5.txt')
line=ofile.readlines()
interestinglines=''
for i in range(len(lines)):
    interestinglines+=(line[lines[i]]+'\n')
```

you may need to tinker with it a bit, but I believe this should reproduce mostly what you're looking for. The `'\n'` is added onto the `line[lines[i]]` so that you may save it to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

After you found the location in string, you can split the String by \n\n and get the first item.

```
s = file_str[namepos2 :]
name = s.split('\n\n')[0]
```